# Meteor not adding a new plugin element in a for each

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table where one of the columns is a Bootstrap Switch element which will be later used to turn on or off the corresponding element of that row.

```
<tbody>

    {{#each sensorslist}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{mac}}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="on-off-checkbox" checked={{state}} />
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}} 

</tbody>
```

However, if I hard code one row, it all works great and the switch always  appears. However, when I load from the sensors list in my database as shown, it only shows when I go to that page by a link (I am using Iron Router). If I press F5, it not shows the Bootstrap Switch.

I am not using autopublish. I am subscribing to the sensors collection in the client:

```
Sensors = new Mongo.Collection("sensors");
Meteor.subscribe('sensors');
```

And to load the data I use this helper:

```
Template.sensores.helpers({

    'sensorslist': function(){ 
        return Sensors.find();
    }

});
```

And also to render the elements I have this as the rendered function:

```
Template.sensores.rendered = function (){

    $('.on-off-checkbox').bootstrapSwitch({
        'offColor': 'danger'
    });

};
```

As I said, if I move around the webapp using only the menu, it works fine, if I refresh the page with F5 or simple go to that page using a direct link it will not work.

I noticed that if I use a setTimeout to execute that code inside the rendered, and add a sufficient amount of time, it will always work, so I guess I am missing something...

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had encountered the same issue as yours ever before.
As I know, when `Template.sensores` is rendered, the data context `sensorslist` is not loaded completely so we can't query the DOM under `sensorslist` block.
But when you use `setTimeout` for a sufficient amount of time, it works as the DOM under `sensorslist` is rendered completely.

My solution for this is using another template additonally:

```
template(name='sensores')
  ...
  <tbody>
    {{#each sensorslist}}
      {{> sensorsList}}
    {{/each}} 
  </tbody>
  ...

template(name='sensorsList')
  <tr>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{mac}}</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="on-off-checkbox" checked={{state}} />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

The Bootstrap Switch is placed in the rendered function of `sensorsList` template.
Since this template will be rendered as many times as the data context `sensorslist`'s length, each DOM we want to manipulate should be scoped within its own template instance.

```
Template.sensorsList.rendered = function () {
  this.$('.on-off-checkbox').bootstrapSwitch({
    'offColor': 'danger'
  });
};
```